# how to find lower bound and upper bound in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
    D1   W1
0.1 23.7 22.4
0.2 25.8 26.88
0.3 29.8 30.64
.
.
.
1.0 24.85 38.31
```

I will give it a value. How to find it in which range of this table?

For example, if I give a value of 27.33, how to find it between 0.2 and 0.3 and then tell me that the upper limit is 29.8 and the lower limit is 25.8?

Comment: indexing by float is not the best idea...

Comment: `df[(0.2 < df.index) & (df.index <= 0.3)].describe()` will give you information including the min/max.

Comment: @QuangHoang whats the downside to using floats as an index?

Comment: @anon01 due to floating point precision, one essentially cannot guarantee access by index.

Comment: OK, I will change the index precision to int thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `searchsorted` from `numpy`

```
idx = np.searchsorted(df.D1,27.33)
df.iloc[idx-1:idx+1,:]
       D1     W1
0.2  25.8  26.88
0.3  29.8  30.64
```

Finding the lower

```
df.iloc[idx-1,:]['D1']
25.8
```